# Using MERGE / CREATE UNIQUE

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm trying to create a unique node if it doesn't exist and connect it to another node if there is no relation.

In this example I want to get or create a Year node for the year 2001. If there already is a 2001 node, I want to create the relation [:YEAR] from calendar if it does not exist, if there is no 2001 node, I want to create both the node and the relation. There is a single node of label Calendar in the db.

```
CREATE UNIQUE (calendar:Calendar)-[:YEAR]->(year:Year {number: 2001 }) RETURN year;

MERGE (calendar:Calendar)-[:YEAR]->(year:Year {number: 2001 }) RETURN year;
```

When I try the queries I get "Unknown error"

What does seem to work is to use one of these

```
MERGE (calendar:Calendar) CREATE UNIQUE (calendar)-[:YEAR]->(year:Year { number:2001} ) RETURN year;

MERGE (calendar:Calendar) MERGE (calendar)-[:YEAR]->(year:Year { number:2001} ) RETURN year;
```

What is the difference between the last two queries, and why doesn't the first ones work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes the neo4j-browser masks exceptions and errors as "Unknown Errors". Try running the queries in neo4j-shell to see the real problem. (I think most recent versions of neo4j-browser lets you see more errors, which version of Neo4j are you using?)

The first query fails because `CREATE UNIQUE` needs some bound identifier to start from, at least one identifier needs to be bound (be 'this'/matter/individual). You can do

```
MATCH (calendar:Calendar)
CREATE UNIQUE calendar-[:YEAR]->(year:Year {number:2001})
RETURN year
```

I don't know why the second query fails, it's not wrong in itself. It won't do what you want, however, for `MERGE` matches or creates the entire pattern. If `(:Calendar)-[:YEAR]->(:Year{number:2001})` exists it will match and return it, if it doesn't exist the whole pattern is created, including a new calendar node. Since the query may create duplicates, could the "Unknown Error" in this case mask some problem with a schema uniqueness constraint?

The third query first binds the calendar node which means the create unique clause has a bound identifier and will work fine.

The fourth query similarly will get-or-create the two patterns separately, which means that no duplicate calendar nodes will be created.

Have you considered modelling the calendar something more like this? It's not relevant to your question, but I think this is probably how I would do it.

```
(:Calendar)-[:2014]->({data:"some year data"})-[:02]->({data:"some month data"})-[:25]->({data:"some day data"})
```

Comment: The webadmin console shows the error messages. From the second query I get " SyntaxException: Somehow, Cypher was not able to construct a valid execution plan from your query." Anyways, as you said, that query is no good. I don't think that other calendar model will work for me, I link days, years and months to events to see which events happened when and I think the current model works better for this.

Answer (score 0):

For the first part you would want to use create unique the below mentioned way. Otherwise it would throw error.

```
MATCH (calendar:Calendar)
CREATE UNIQUE (calendar)-[:YEAR]->(year:Year {number: 2001 }) 
RETURN year;
```

Now for the second query you dont need to use CREATE UNIQUE because MERGE does job of both MATCH and CREATE UNIQUE together.

```
MERGE (calendar:Calendar)-[:YEAR]->(year:Year { number:2001} ) RETURN year;
```

The above will create whatever nodes, relationships and labels that dont exist and in the same time reuse what already exist.

More info on Cypher MERGE : [here](http://blog.neo4j.org/2013/05/new-milestone-release-neo4j-200-m03.html)